# How To add Javascript In header of Prestashop

Tags: javascript, prestashop

I am trying to adding custom script in the main header of the prestashop but it is not working. may be i am doing wrong

```
     <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
      <script type="text/javascript" data-keepinline="true">
        jQuery(".category_drop_menu").click(function () {
        alert("asdas");
        });
        </script>
```

Please help me how i can add my custom script in prestashop header.tpl

Answer (score 0):

Not sure what the problem is. I changed it a little but I think your example should work.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $(".category_drop_menu").click(function() {
    alert("Works");
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<button class="category_drop_menu">Click</button>
```

Comment: Thanks Its Working for me. But I am saying not working in prestasope template... Please try by click on Blue Button with logo.@Will
https://www.silkroadsavdo.com/en/